# Variable height of a UITableViewCell when heightForRow not an option

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I kind of an odd scenario where I have a `UITableViewCell` that has a label that can have a variable amount of text. I've looked at a few answers here dealing with this (to set the correct cell height), and a lot of them solve them like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [indexPath row] * //some logic that looks at the text amount and adjusts accordingly;
}
```

The issue I have is, the code base I inherited has a *highly* coupled process where the text for the label is retrieved in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and so when `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called the object where the text is retrieved is `nil`.

I tried making the object an ivar, but alas, it depends on another datasource that is all instantiated in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

So assuming that having the text of the UILabel is **not** available in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, is there a good way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Storyboards?

Comment: @AMayes Not here, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an array which store the height of each now. Initially populate entire array with some constant value.
When cellForRow is called and that text is fetched, then calculate the new height and store that in heights array.And now call `reloadData of tableView`.

You can even use animations while increasing height.

you can even use `– reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

Comment: good idea, let me try this tonight and if it works I will accept this

Answer (score 0):

When I have variable-sized cells I usually find it too painful to have separate implementations of figuring out what the size is.  So what I do instead is in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`  I just call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get the cell and the work to configure the size of internal elements is done there.

Of course that means I build the cell twice. So far the inefficiency has not been a performance issue when I've done it -- a few cells visible and human-interaction speeds.  Presumably if it were a performance issue I could construct my own small cache of configured cells.

Perhaps this technique would work for you.